# How to create mirrored image effect with CSS single element

Tags: html, css, image-effects

I have an HTML element with a background image and want to create a mirror effect to the bottom, as if the image is reflected like this:

[image: Image with mirror]

The optimal solution for me to create this reflection would be CSS only without using more elements than this single one and without using the image URL multiple times (due to maintenance reasons). I only found [solutions like this](http://hsrtech.com/css/create-reflection-effect-using-css3/) with "complicated" HTML markup.

This is my code:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/P56gr.jpg);
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/P56gr.jpg);
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  bottom: -210px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Sort of similar (it was with text) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32651639/reflecting-text-with-gradient-effect-in-css/32651828#32651828

Comment: Thanks for this hint!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can indeed use the pseudo-elements `:after` and `:before` to first mirror the image using `transform: scaleY(-1);` and second overlay the mirrored image with a linear gradient going from a semi-transparent white `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)` to non-transparent white `#fff`.

To not being forced to notate the image URL twice, just use `background: inherit;`.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/P56gr.jpg) bottom;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
div:after,
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: inherit;
  height: 50%;
  bottom: -52%;
}
div:after {
  background: inherit;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
div:before {
  z-index: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), #fff);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

*Note*: You have to use vendor prefixes for support in different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
transform: rotate(180deg);
-webkit-mask-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left 50%, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,.7)), to(rgba(0,0,0,1)));
```

Obviously nothing will be cross-browser 100% when doing stuff like this in css

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/P56gr.jpg);
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/P56gr.jpg);
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  bottom: -210px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-mask-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left 50%, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,0)), to(rgba(0,0,0,.5)));
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Andreas answer probably has more vendor support. mask-image is not widely supported, but when it is, you were 95% there.

Comment: This doesn't add a mirror image along the horizontal axis. Note how the curve in the water goes the wrong way. You want to use rotateX(180deg) instead of rotate(180deg).

Comment: Nice catch. I didn't even notice.

Comment: Rotate 180 is not the same as a mirror operation ! it's a double mirror operation (see group theory eventually)