# Specify stops in gradient opacity (mask-image)

Tags: css, linear-gradients

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181392/how-to-create-mirrored-image-effect-with-css-single-element), I was able to get the code below to work.

However, it's not exactly like I want.  I want it to fade out sooner.  After some research, it looks like `gradient` (and `webkit-gradient`) have been replaced with `linear-gradient`.  I tried to use that, but it doesn't seem to work with `mask-image`.

So, how can I make an image fade out with specific stops?  For example 0 opacity at 0%, .25 opacity at 75%, .5 opacity at 100%. (In other words, you wouldn't see the red and blue stripes until 75% of the way down the image)

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  -webkit-mask-image:
    -webkit-gradient(
      linear,
      left top,
      left bottom,
      from(
        rgba(0,0,0,1)
      ), to(
        rgba(0,0,0,0)
      )
    )

}

#bg1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; width: 50px;
  height: 360px;
  background-color: red;
}
#bg2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px; width: 50px;
  height: 360px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg">
<div id="bg1"></div>
<div id="bg2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linear-gradient()` will do

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 75%, transparent);
  mask-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 75%, transparent);
}

#bg1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; width: 50px;
  height: 360px;
  background-color: red;
}
#bg2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px; width: 50px;
  height: 360px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg">
<div id="bg1"></div>
<div id="bg2"></div>
```